# How do I load files using Selenium Webdriver/xUnit/c# on Edge? It works on other browsers

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xunit.net

I have code written in C# using Selenium Webdriver and xUnit that needs to load files from disk.

Here's the input HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="DICOMInput" webkitdirectory="" allowdirs="" directory="" multiple="">

<button id="LoadFilesButton" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button"><span class="ui-button-text">Next</span></button>
```

And here's the code that I use:

```
IWebElement buttonUpload = driver.FindElement(By.Id("DICOMInput"));
string FilePath = "Insert path to file here";
buttonUpload.SendKeys(FilePath);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoadFilesButton")).Click();
```

It works fine in FireFox and IE but not in Edge. In Edge I get a dialog saying "Please choose a file". Anyone know of a way to get this to work with Edge?

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using ? Also are you testing Edge locally or via selenium grid (jar or docker) ?

Comment: Locally. And Selenium.Webdriver 3.141.0, Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools 3.141.0